# Cassandra Nodetool Listsnapshots output is unclear

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

What is **true size** in the output of the command `nodetool listsnapshots`?

There is no explanation in the Cassandra documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the total size of sstables that only that snapshot has a hardlink of.

Snapshots just create hardlinks to the actual sstable component. Once compacted and deleted away the hardlink in the snapshot may be only link referencing the inode and preventing it from being freed. Thats what it will measure.

For example if you disable compaction and take a snapshot, immediately after the listsnapshots will show true size as zero. If you turn node off, and delete one sstable in the data directory then restart, the listsnapshots will show true size as the size of the deleted sstable.

Comment: Also, true size can be thought of as the amount of actual disk space that the snapshot is consuming **on top of** the existing normal sstable data. For example, right after taking the snapshot, true size will be 0 because the snapshot is fresh and is simply linking to your existing data (it's not consuming any extra disk space). But in a couple of days, true size will increase, indicating that your snapshots are consuming this much extra disk space on top your existing data in order to keep the snapshot alive.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a while and couldn't find anything in the Cassandra docs - however, the [Scylladb docs](https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/nodetool-commands/listsnapshots/) (Scylla being itself derived from Cassandra) says **true size** is *"Total size of all SSTables which are not backed up to disk"*.

Further reading offers the following example:

> There is a single 1TB file in the snapshot directory. If that file also exists in the main column family directory, the size on the disk is 1TB and the true size is 0 because it is already backed up to disk.

It seems "true size" is the amount of data that has not yet been backed up - if your backups are fresh, it will be 0.